# Restricting a user to access only his/her entities In Entity framework6 Repository pattern

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns, asp.net-mvc-5, repository-pattern

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC5 project with **Repository pattern** for the first time. It has lots of roles and there will be number of user in each role. Till now, I have created various model entities and add, update, delete scenarios are working fine. During testing things, I found that a user is able to update those entities that do not belong to him/her.

I want to restrict the user to access, edit, update, delete only those entities (Rows in db) that belong to the user itself, not the other ones.

I know, I need to check somewhere the `userId` of the current logged in user, but where should I put this where condition in case of `Repository pattern with Entity Framework`.

Two ways that come to my mind are: Changing the models to have `userId` property in each entity or joining each entity with it's parent entity to get the related user details (The complete chain of entities to get the `userId`).

What would be the preferred way to implement this?
Thanks!

Comment: Start at the beginning: what is your desired bussiness purpose. In other words how does the functionality need to work? Is it possible to restrict data access based on user / role somewhere in the hierarchy of your domain model? Or do you want each and every entity to have a related user(Id) and so have a restriction on every level of your domain model?

Comment: This is not possible on role basis as there will be lots of users in same role. Only `userId` can make sure that the an entity is related to him/her or not.

Comment: Why do they have the possibility to make these disallowed modifications to begin with? Do you mean they shouldn't even *see* other users' data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `SaveChanges` method from `DbContext` and check if a user is only changing his/her own entities. This solution will work in any pattern which is using EntityFramework.

First you need to write an Interface that has `UserId` and every entities must implement it.

```
public interface IEntity   
{
    int UserId { get; set; }
}

public Blog : IEntity
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Then you need to override `SaveChanges`. In this method if an entity is being modified or deleted, we check if UserId matches, otherwise you throw exception.
and for the entities that is being added you can assign current UserId

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {

        var ModifiedDeletedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries()
              .Where(E => E.State == EntityState.Deleted ||
                          E.State == EntityState.Modified).ToList();
        foreach (IEntity entity in ModifiedDeletedEntities)
        {
            if (entity.UserId != GetCurrentUserId())
            {
                throw new Exception("Access Denied!");
            }
        }



        var AddedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries()
               .Where(E => E.State == EntityState.Added).ToList();
        foreach (IEntity entity in AddedEntities)
        {
            entity.UserId = GetCurrentUserId();
        }



            return base.SaveChanges();

    }
```

Comment: That's a very late warning. If the application allows users to modify other users' data it may not be possible for a user to store their *valid* part of the changes anymore. I think the focus should be to prevent disallowed modifications.

Comment: This seems good, but in my application I have some roles (e.g., Support) that can edit some user related data. Can we even modify this solution to work on role basis to allow some roles to carry on editing the other user data and prevent some roles to do so.

Comment: @vivek yes you can modify this solution to your needs. All you have to do is change the if statement `if (entity.UserId != GetCurrentUserId())` to whatever condition you want.

Answer (score 0):

Joining each entity with it's parent entity to get the related user details (The complete chain of entities to get the userId) would be good. Create a BaseEntity that will have common property Like **UserId** -

```
public class BaseEntity {
    public int UserId {get;set;}
}
```

Other entities will inherit the base entity so that they can inherently have the common UserId property -

```
public class OtherEntity : BaseEntity {
    // properties
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use the a new SQL Server 2016 feature : row level security.
(also available on Azure)

With this, you can filter query result at database level.

A good starting point for this : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-entity-framework-row-level-security/